# Ошибка при запуске приложения на реальном устройстве

Tags: android

Загружаю приложение на телефон в режиме отладки, в конце загрузки выдаёт такие ошибки:

```
E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4494 (*имя пакета*)
```

В итоге приложение установлено, но не запускается, сразу вылетает.
Версия андроид поддерживаемая, если запускаю в эмуляторе на такой же версии, то всё работает.

Из-за чего возникают такие ошибки и как это исправить?

Полный стекрейс:

```
2023-01-26 14:55:01.900 10403-10403/? W/main: type=1400 audit(0.0:60477): avc: denied { search } for name="block" dev="tmpfs" ino=495 scontext=u:r:zygote:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:block_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2023-01-26 14:55:01.911 10403-10403/? W/Zygote: mz_is_rooted false
2023-01-26 14:55:01.912 10403-10403/? W/Zygote: Failed to unmount /storage/emulated: Invalid argument
2023-01-26 14:55:01.912 10403-10403/? W/Zygote: Failed to unmount /storage: Invalid argument
2023-01-26 14:55:01.914 10403-10403/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-01-26 14:55:02.139 10403-10403/com.ov.myapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
2023-01-26 14:55:02.306 10403-10403/com.ov.myapp E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
2023-01-26 14:55:02.333 10403-10403/com.ov.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10403 (com.ov.myapp)
```

Comment: Полный стекрейс приведите.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, добавила